# Where does LineageOs store update files?

Tags: twrp, ota-update, lineageos

Back in cyanogenmod, updates were downloaded to the cmupdater directory.
Then I could easily use twrp recovery to install the Upgrade.

But where does LineageOs store its downloaded upgrade files?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As of the new updates of August 31st, 2017, the updates are stored in

```
/data/lineageos_updates
```

Comment: Should be marked as an answer.

Comment: On my current LineageOS (14.1) this appears to be incorrect as of 30 April 2018. I would have added an answer, but my Segfault and Poweruser and other stackexchange site reps don't carry over. My LineageOS updates are in the directory: "/LineageOS updates/" (in Internal Storage). This is confirmed via ASTRO on an active LineageOS 14.1 system.

Comment: This works with LineageOS 17.1

Answer (score 36):

Browse to folder:

`/data/data/org.lineageos.updater/app_updates`

edit: per comments below, this is outdated and the top answer is correct.

Comment: Don't you know if it will be changed to a more convenient one like ```cmupdater``` on storage dir ?

Comment: No idea. I ended up encrypting my phone so I have to sideload each time anyway.

Comment: I think this answer with 32 votes is outdated.  They seem to have moved it mid-2017.  See other answer above.

Comment: This answer is correct for Lineage OS15.1 for kuntao/Lenovo P2 as of the time of writing - I have just tried it. What may further confuse the issue is that for an encrypted phone, when you press install it reboots the phone into recovery without mounting all storage, so some files may not be visible.