# LineageOS update files not present in /data/lineageos_updates since 27th April 2018

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-4, lineageos

Since the update from 20th April 2018, I can't find the LineageOS update in the [current path](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182952/233637) which is `/data/lineageos_updates` . When I download the latest update (27th April 2018) and reboot in TWRP, there is no corresponding update file in the folder. After a reboot, the updater in the settings show me that this update isn't downloaded - altouth it did before the reboot.

Comments say that they found the update in `/LineageOS updates/` (internal storage) but on the Samsung Galaxy S4 it doesn't contain the latest update. Only a outdated version of February. No idea, how those old update got there. I didn't ever now that those folder exist. I only know `/data/linageos_updates` as current update location store and `/data/data/org.lineageos.updater/app_updates` for older updates before August 31st, 2017.

So in the current situation, I'm not able to update LineageOS on this Galaxy S4 directly. I want to avoid downloading the update from a PC and moving it to the device since it's not mine and the owner is a non-technical user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the causing issue, but have found a workaround for fixing: I downloaded all avaliable updates (the owner last updated in March) and bootet TWRP. Now I searched for the last update that I found in `/data/lineageos_updates` and installed it.

In my case, it was from 10th of April. This update seems to be something special: The updater say it's from 10th of April, where the [LineageOS download page list it as 11th of April](https://download.lineageos.org/jfltexx). I installed the update and every single following update by hand. This worked and made them visible in the expected `/data/lineageos_update` path.

Don't know what's the reason for this. I assume that some changes were made on the update process in one of those update (maybe the one from 11th of April or another one) and those changes weren't included properly in the following updates. But at least those steps are a workaround, when you're not able to install the latest LineageOS update any more.